# How open a popup.html without new tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a extension example, and popup window is opened as new tab.

So, now I want open this popup window in same Chrome active tab like this:

[image]

I already have tried several way, but without success until now.

**PS:** I'm using Google Chrome V.50

Here is code that open my popup in a new tab:

***manifest.json***

```
{  
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["action.js"],
    "persistent": false
},

    "name": "W3C cheatsheet",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Show the W3C cheatsheet on a popup",

    "icons": { "48": "favicon.png" },

    "browser_action": {

            "default_icon": "favicon.png"

    },
    "permissions": ["http://*/", "tabs"]
}
```

***action.js***

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('w3c.html'), 'selected': true});
});
```

***popup.html***  (*w3c.html* in this case)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
</script>
<style>* {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="https://www.w3.org/2009/cheatsheet/" width="450" height="500"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "open this popup window in same Chrome active tab"? Do you want to replace the existing content of the active tab?

Comment: @JackA., I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***SOLVED:***

In *manifest.json*:

```
"browser_action": {

"default_popup": "w3c.html"

},
```

Answer (score 1):

W3 Schools says that to open a new window, you must use `window.open("url here");`

Try this code:

`window.open({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('w3c.html'), 'selected': true});`